# How to use NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, osx-yosemite, nstitlebaraccessoryviewcontroller

Can anyone tell me how to use NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController, to add subview to a view with an example? As I am new to mac programming you may have to explain from basics. Please.

Answer (score 16):

`NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController` is for adding subviews to the windows title bar.

Here is a example:
Set up a `view` in interface builder. Go to the `applicationDidFinishLaunching: method to add the view to the title bar.

The code would be the following:

```
NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController* vc = [[NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController alloc] init];

vc.view = self.view;
vc.layoutAttribute = NSLayoutAttributeRight;

[self.window addTitlebarAccessoryViewController:vc];
```

You can play with the size of the view to make it fit into the title bar.

**Update**

OS X 10.11 introduced the new `layoutAttribute` `left`. 
There are now three `layoutAttribute`s in total. `bottom` adds a bar beneath the titleBar (like the tabBar) and `left`/`right` places your subview within the titleBar.